# WP Load post with ajax and apply isotope

Tags: posts, theme-development, jquery, ajax

I ma using `Ajax Load More` to get my posts and show in a frontend, then I have applied isotope to the items. When I first show some items and applied isotope, it's working perfectly.

But When second time I load post by ajax and try to apply the isotope, that isotope is not working and posts are overriding.

Could someone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this question. I need to apply there Isotope append method, when adding posts to the frontend. [Here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#appended) is the Isotope append method.